# How to force figures and legends to the next page if there is not enough space on the current page, swapping with the next paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, styles, pictures, page

I am writing my thesis and this structure of styles are common in my `.docx` file (each line represents one paragraph):

---

```
Using style named "Main text": main text 1, paragraph break
(Using style named "Figure": Figure, paragraph break
Using style named "Figure Title": Figure Title, paragraph break
Using style named "Figure Legend": Figure Legend, paragraph break)*1 or repeat
Using style named "Main text": main text 2
```

---

Sometimes, the `Figure` is too large to fit in the end of a page, such that it flows to the next page. The problem is that this will create a *big* empty space at the end of the current page. So, what I want to do is that when this happens, **Word** automatically helps me to rearrage the content to remove the empty spaces and utilize the page better. As in the above examples, I would like **Word** to format it to something like this:

---

```
Using style named "Main text": main text 1, paragraph break
Using style named "Main text": Part of main text 2, paragraph break (on the same page, fill to the bottom of the page)
Using style named "Figure": Figure, paragraph break (at the start of the next page)
Using style named "Figure Title": Figure Title, paragraph break
Using style named "Figure Legend": Figure Legend, paragraph break
Using style named "Main text": Remaining part of main text 2
```

---

Anyone knows how to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have page breaks anywhere? Are your figures inline with text (Sounds like yes)? Have you tried using wraparound instead?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes I am using figures inline with text. But even changing the wrapping option (such as wraparound) does not help. No page break used. Only paragraph break. Let me supplement the question.

Comment: Add a manual page break. You probably won't get this behavior out of the box. If you wanted to you'd need to create a box and put your whole figure in it and make text flow around it or would need to use a different system like LaTeX. Which isn't WYSIWG but rather has a proper typeset system.

Comment: I agree with @Seth - I don't think there's a way for this to be automated. Your best bet is to manually place all figures in the text and ajust manually

Comment: Thank you. Regret not having learnt LaTeX... But I think I might just have the editing done after finalizing the thesis.

Comment: Layout should always be done *after* the writing is done